# Spark Streaming 2.0 GC Error (Shuffle Issue)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

My kafka topics have millions of messages in them, unfortunately Spark Streaming seems to queue all of the messages no matter the time limit I get. I have set my standalone server with 16 cores and 64GB RAM, I've given my driver 12G and the Executor 12G of Memory.

```
16/09/14 19:27:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 10.206.41.172): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at com.twitter.chill.Tuple4Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:68)
        at com.twitter.chill.Tuple4Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:59)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:396)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:307)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readValue(Serializer.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.readNextItem(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:515)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.hasNext(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:535)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1004)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.org$apache$spark$util$collection$ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator$$readNextHashCode(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator$$anonfun$5.apply(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator$$anonfun$5.apply(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:314)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.<init>(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:314)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.iterator(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:695)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:691)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:691)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


        org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: /tmp/spark-e4238a07-bf89-4a7d-9de3-176cba0a076d/executor-93a11b25-1cb1-4e13-b1b6-b1d64d3a9602/blockmgr-c11cd046-7c37-429c-9137-936d391d3cbc/30/shuffle_0_0_0.index (No such file or directory)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:357)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:332)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-e4238a07-bf89-4a7d-9de3-176cba0a076d/executor-93a11b25-1cb1-4e13-b1b6-b1d64d3a9602/blockmgr-c11cd046-7c37-429c-9137-936d391d3cbc/30/shuffle_0_0_0.index (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getBlockData(BlockManager.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchLocalBlocks(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.initialize(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.<init>(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:45)
        ... 9 more


java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any recommendations on what I can do to handle this? Is my solution going to be just feed it more memory? I pointing at a shuffle issue because one exeuctor has:

Shuffle Read Size/Records: 815.5 MB / 27445419

Shuffle Spill (memory): 13GB

Shuffle Spill (Disk): 697.4 MB

I have no idea what it might be shuffling.

```
val messageStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder, (String, Int, Long, String)](ssc, getKafkaBrokers(), getKafkaTopics("raw"), (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => {
      (mmd.topic, mmd.partition, mmd.offset, mmd.message)
    })

    //first step is to take our RDD of messages and group them by the topic (x._1) and partition (x._2)
    messageStream.foreachRDD(x => x.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).foreach(x => {
      //Populate parameters based on the grouping and get the instruction sets to run on each message
      val rawTopic: String = x._1._1
      val partitionID: Int = x._1._2
      val sourceSystemName: String = rawTopic.split("_")(0)
      val cleanTopic = sourceSystemName + "_clean"
      val topicID = getTopicID(rawTopic)
      val schemaID = getPartitionByTopic(topicID).filter(x => x._1 == partitionID)(0)._2
      val classpath = getClasspath(schemaID.toInt)
      val classPath = bcClassMap.value.get(classpath)
      val cleanerObj = classPath.newInstance()
      val cleanMethod = classPath.getMethod("clean", Class.forName("java.lang.String"))

      //For each message run the instruction sets we've gotten above
      x._2.foreach(kafkaMessage => {
        val offset: Long = kafkaMessage._3
        val rawRecord: String = kafkaMessage._4
        val cleanRecord = cleanMethod.invoke(cleanerObj, rawRecord).asInstanceOf[String]
        if (cleanRecord != null) {
          sendKafka(cleanRecord, cleanTopic, partitionID.toString)
        }
        offsetUpdate(schemaID, offset.toInt, topicID)
      })
    }))
```

Comment: Added in code. I have a lot of built in functions but happy to elaborate on any of them.

Comment: I gave the driver 30GB of ram and seemed to not crash, but still concerned about that spill over.

Comment: This `groupBy` smells bad. Is there anything that really justifies it? Since it looks like you process individual messages separately anyway what is the point of that?

Comment: The reason I have it because it lowers the amount of calls to the getTopicID, getPartitionByTopic, getClasspath, so for every grouping of messages we call it just once. Rather than call it for each message. I don't want to murder my API server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious suspect here is the initial `groupBy`.

While it can be maintainable in a batch application, when you have some idea about data distribution, it is simply not acceptable in a streaming application, where single skewed batch can break a whole pipeline. Even if it doesn't come that far it can cripple overall performance.

Since your code doesn't really depend on the grouping and it is only an optimization attempt you're in a pretty good situation. You can for example:

- Drop `groupBy` completely.
- Use shared cache for each partition or executor to handle expensive API calls.

If number of API calls is still to high you can generate salted partitioning keys:

```
_.keyBy(x => (x._1, x._2, smallRandomInteger))
```

and repartition each RDD.

You could use salting for `groupBy` as well but if used like this you address only data skews not the cost of grouping and maintaining large local buffers.

Comment: What do you mean by: "shared cache for each partition or executor"

Comment: An object which will serve as a proxy for the external API and maintains cache for different method calls. If responses are constant over time you handle this per executor (singleton object should do just fine), otherwise you can use `mapPartitions` and initialize cache there.

Comment: Would it be cheaper to just .map(x => ((x._1, x._2), (x._3, x._4))) than repartition? I feel like keyBy will add extra information that may be accomplished in this format?

Comment: It would be cheaper. I though you prefer this format for some reason and that is why you use `groupBy`.